# How to build AIR Native Extension for Windows with C#?

Tags: c#, windows, air, actionscript-3, ane

I recently developed native extensions for mobile projects on Adobe AIR (Android and iOS).

I want to port these ANEs for desktop projects on Windows and OSX. The OSX part is not a problem because it uses the same mechanisms as for iOS. The problem is essentially on the Windows side.

Adobe AIR offers bridges to write the native part in C / C ++, I prefer to use C# to simplify the task and access more simply .NET libraries.

Has anyone ever heard of experiments or viable projects to code a native Adobe AIR extension with C#?

I have not found a complete solution to achieve this:

- Create a DLL in C # including access to FlashRuntimeExtensions.h (C Header file)
- Be able to use .NET libraries from this unique DLL
- Produce only one DLL file
- Do not use the flash.desktop.NativeProcess library

Thank you for your help or a different point of view on these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A developer sent me [this link](https://github.com/tuarua/FreSharp) to TUARUA's FreSharp GitHub page.

It corresponds exactly to the subject of my question. I share it so that everyone can see how to create an ANE (AIR Native Extension) from C# under Windows.

So I will be able to resume my development and port my libraries for desktop computers.

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

According to [**Extending AIR**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html), you just need access to any function on your DLL regardless what native method you used to create it.

This means that you still need to use a C++ project to link AIR to your native library but the main code can be done on C#. So you export your main code/logic into a DLL from C# and then use the C++ bridge project to Link both DLL and flash.

This link could also be useful : [**Windows ANE - tutorial introduction**](http://easynativeextensions.com/windows-tutorial-introduction/)

Comment: Thanks for these links. I have read them many times. But this is actually a very good starting point for other AS3 developers interested in the subject.